# How to add an array of an array to values of hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I have an array a1 and an array-of-arrays a2.

```
@a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and

```
@a2 = [ [adf],[bcg],[yet],[gpd],[iop]]
```

I want to have a hash where a1 are the keys and arrays of a2 as values. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to do it.  Your syntax is a bit off in your question so I'm going to assume my variable declarations are what you wanted.

```perl
my @a1 = (1,2,3,4,5);
my @a2 = ( ["a", "d", "f"], ["b", "c", "g"], ["y","e","t"], 
           ["g", "p", "d"], ["i", "o", "p"] );
# Thus $a2[0][1] => "d", etc.                                                                                                                                           

#Perl 5.12 and higher you can use "each" on an array
my %a3;
while (my ($a1_index, $a1_value) = each @a1) {
    $a3{$a1_value} = $a2[$a1_index];
}
# Now @{$a3{4}} => ["g", "p", "d"] for example

# Before 5.12 you would have to do something like this:
my %a4;
for my $i (0..$#a1) {
    $a4{$a1[$i]} = $a2[$i];
}
# Now @{$a4{4}} => ["g", "p", "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @keys = (1,2,3,4,5);
my @vals = ( ["a", "d", "f"], ["b", "c", "g"], ["y","e","t"], 
           ["g", "p", "d"], ["i", "o", "p"] );

my $hash={};

for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@keys); $i++){

    $hash->{$keys[$i]}=$vals[$i];
}

#print the resulted hash
use Data::Dumper;print Dumper($hash);
```

Result looks like:
$VAR1 = {
          '4' => [
                   'g',
                   'p',
                   'd'
                 ],
          '1' => [
                   'a',
                   'd',
                   'f'
                 ],
          '3' => [
                   'y',
                   'e',
                   't'
                 ],
          '2' => [
                   'b',
                   'c',
                   'g'
                 ],
          '5' => [
                   'i',
                   'o',
                   'p'
                 ]
        };

Perl hashes are unordered so don't worry about the order in which they are printed here, you could sort them based on the numeric keys if necessary.